# Call javascript function based on Fragment ID

Tags: javascript, function, web, fragment-identifier

Please dont ask why I would want to do this, I just want to know if it's possible to call a javascript function if and only if a specific fragment ID is present. Thanks :)

(Yes this links with my previous question, but it was too dissimilar to append on to it) if this is not possible, is there another way of calling a javascript function based on the URL.

Comment: Can you share a bit more details, please?

Comment: Please add more details. I read your other question, and now I have a guess about what you mean, but I'm not sure. Are you talking about `onclick=...`?

Comment: Yes this is possible. Post some code an maybe we can help you more detailed :)

Comment: It#s been answered, I though I was clear. When a page is loaded with a fragment ID, can I run a function base on that ID, the guy bellow answers it perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Of course it is. You can get the fragment, check it's value and then call a function if it matches.

```
if (window.location.hash == "#myfragment") {
    myFunction();
}
```

Comment: Explain how to do all this please, I'm only just starting out with Function ID's :)

Comment: I'll accept this in 9 minutes when I can, thankyou so much :)

Comment: Ahhh... Running this with the #about ID, trying to call that about(), the result of the about() function is not working, I've checked it works normally as theres another thing that calls about on that page when clicked.